# Android Studio: more info about "Error installing app"

Tags: android, android-studio

When trying to run the app on the device, I'm facing the following issue:

[image]

I the Event Log, there is the same message:

[image]

Where can I find more info about the error?

Comment: are you using `Xiomi` phone ?

Comment: No, however the phone type is not important here - I'm just asking about more detailed error message.

Comment: disable instant run go to file settings - > build execution run and then uncheck enable instant run and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Might work if you Clean the project or rebuild the project and if you launching in emulator uninstall from the emulator or from mobile.

**UPDATE:**

i think there will be no more information about the error...
It's our common mistakes.

As per my knowledge about this issue there can be a few reasons for that:

1. First is that your app is already installed with the same package
   name but with different certificate, To resolve this check if your
   phone has that app already installed then uninstall it and try to
   install new one.
2. The second reason can be that you are trying to install the
   application that has minimum SDK version higher than the Android
   version of device. To solve this make sure that the minimum SDK
   version defined in your project's "build.gradle" is lower than the
   Android version of your device.
3. Turning off the Instant run removed error for Android Studio 2.3.
4. sometimes project location contained the special character.

**Example:** E:\Android_Projects\T&PUIET,KUK\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

close android studio > rename folder containing the special character(here T&PUIET,KUK ) > restart android studio.

Hope it will help!

Comment: "i think there will be no more information about the error" - is it a confirmed information?

Comment: Yes.I have researched many question like this.. and in that it says to follow this rule.